# Is retrieving all posts from friends still possible in the Graph API post-v2.3?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In the v2.3 Facebook Graph API, the `[user]/posts` endpoint returns all that friend's posts.

That endpoint was replaced with `/feed` from v2.4 onwards. However, it seems that the new endpoint provides significantly less access and that's not acknowledged anywhere in the documentation. Am I missing something important?

The [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/feed) about the v2.5 `/feed` endpoints says,

> Your app needs user_posts permission **from the person who created the
>   post** or the person tagged in the post.

This seems to mean that, under v2.5, it's only possibly to retrieve the feed of the authenticated user and not their friends. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. There´s not really anything else to add, you can´t get the whole feed anymore for privacy reasons.

See "`user_posts`" in v2.3: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_3

Comment: Interesting. Striking that Facebook removed such a significant part of that API in a point upgrade, without even calling it out.

Comment: without even calling it out? it IS in the changelog, and it was discussed a lot of times in the facebook dev group on facebook. it was an obvious update, because no app should have any business getting access to posts of other users who did not authorize the app.